# Apache 2.4 & Ubuntu 14.04 error on Vagrant: "You don't have permission to access / on this server."

Tags: ubuntu, virtualhost, apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04, vagrant

I realize there are a lot of similar questions on here, but I've been struggling with this for hours and have been unable to find a solution.

When I try visiting my Vagrant Ubuntu box via the host name `shopwise.dev` (set to the Vagrant box's IP in `/etc/hosts`), I get the following error page:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at shopwise.dev Port 80
```

I created the file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/shopwise.conf`:

```
ServerName host.foxytronics.com
NameVirtualHost *:80

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory "/home/shopws/public_html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin myemail@gmail.com
    ServerName www.shopwise.dev
    ServerAlias shopwise.dev

    DirectoryIndex index.php
    Options FollowSymLinks
    DocumentRoot "/home/shopws/public_html"

    # Logfiles
    ErrorLog  /home/shopws/logs/apache/error.log
    CustomLog /home/shopws/logs/apache/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Then ran:

```
sudo a2ensite shopwise.conf
service apache2 reload
```

I verified the directory permissions along the path `/home/shopws/public_html` are `755` and the file permissions are also currently `755` (although I think they're actually supposed to be `644`?).

Is my configuration incorrect?

UPDATE:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: `NameVirtualHost *:80` has no effect in apache 2.4.x. Does the directory actually contain an index file ?

Comment: @drookie Thanks for your reply! Yes, there is an index.php file here: `/home/shopws/public_html/index.php`. One thing that just occurred to me is that the files are "owned" by the user `vagrant`. Could it be that Apache isn't able to open the files because it doesn't "own" them? I guess that is kind of a Vagrant-specific question..

Comment: nope, owner is not the reason since you have sufficient permissions. what will happen if you will request http://shopwise.dev/index.php exactly ?

Comment: @drookie I see the same error when going to that URL. I added a few screenshots to my question, for what it's worth..

Comment: And what does the apachectl -S show ?

Comment: @drookie Added a screenshot. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: What about error log file, what do you see there, maybe paste here?
Who is the owner of /home/shopws/ and subfolders (you should have vagrant).
Do you have an index.something?

Comment: `root` is the owner of `/home`,  vagrant is the owner of `/home/shopws` on down. I'm not sure what you mean by `index.something`? I'm having trouble finding the error logs, but will post them once I do. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The error log file hasn't been created, then. Yes, there is an index.php file at `/home/shopws/public_html/index.php`.

Answer (score 2):

As usual, my issue was totally my fault and due to my ignorance :-)

I needed to use the `Directory` directive to grant users permission to access the directory I chose to put my site's files in. This is my final working configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin myemail@gmail.com
    ServerName www.shopwise.dev
    ServerAlias shopwise.dev

    DocumentRoot /home/shopws/public_html

    # Logfiles
    ErrorLog  /home/shopws/logs/apache/error.log
    CustomLog /home/shopws/logs/apache/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<Directory /home/shopws/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I hope that helps someone else someday!

Comment: Just saved my day! :-)

Answer (score -1):

By index.something I mean index.html, index.php, etc.
Here is your error file:
 ErrorLog  /home/shopws/logs/apache/error.log

step 1
tail -f /home/shopws/logs/apache/error.log

step 2
hit Refresh or F5 on the browser, you should see something here, if not do the same but with:
tail -f /home/shopws/logs/apache/access.log

And you should also see something here, and paste the last lines here.

Comment: The error log file hasn't been created, then. Yes, there is an index.php file at `/home/shopws/public_html/index.php`. Also, you should update your other answer or post a comment on your other answer instead of posting a new answer :-)

Comment: Well I'm kinda new to this.

Comment: But what about access.log???